# HTML canvas text entry and backspace

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas element which I would like to make interactive by allowing users to enter text and remove it. Adding text works as expected, however deletion using the backspace key triggers the browser's back action.

How can I stop this action?

Cheers,
A.

Comment: Does anyone know where this crazy backspace=back-button idea originally came from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `keydown` event. Add the handler either to the document (bad, because it disables expected browser behaviour on the rest of the page, not just the `<canvas>` element) or give your `<canvas>` element a tabindex and add the `keypress` handler to it (better).

```
function preventBackspaceHandler(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 8) {
        return false;
    }
}

document.onkeydown = preventBackspaceHandler;
```

Comment: I think that while using Google Chrome you cannot prevent this from clicking back button, IMO.

Comment: I just tested it in Chrome and it seemed to work OK (backspace did not make the browser go back to the previous page).