# Remove backspace default behaviour in Elm

Tags: html, canvas, elm

[I'm having more or less the same issues as this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268918/html-canvas-text-entry-and-backspace), except that I'm programming in Elm.

I have a canvas that I use to enter some text, but I want to press backspace to remove characters. When I press backspace, the browser just go back to his last page.

I tried something like that, but it doesn't work.

```
canvas : Signal Element
canvas = Signal.map2(\(w, h) t -> Collage.collage w h [t]) Window.dimensions writtenText

mb = Signal.mailbox ()

removeDefaultBackspace = onWithOptions "onKeyDown" {defaultOptions | preventDefault = True} keyCode (\_ -> Signal.message  mb.address ())

main = Signal.map (\c -> Html.body [removeDefaultBackspace] [Html.fromElement c]) canvas
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been playing around with this for a while and the only workaround I can get to work is the one linked in that other [stackoverflow post you mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268918/html-canvas-text-entry-and-backspace).

In the javascript, before wiring up the Elm module, if you attach to the document `onkeydown` event, you'll be able to suppress top-level backspaces.

```js
function preventBackspaceHandler(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 8) {
        return false;
    }
}

document.onkeydown = preventBackspaceHandler;

var app = Elm.fullscreen(Elm.Main);
```

Comment: What do you do with the app variable after?

Comment: It isn't necessary to assign to the `app` variable unless you're going to communicate to javascript using ports. See the documentation on [ports](http://elm-lang.org/guide/interop) (it uses `myapp` instead of `app` as a variable name but the same concept applies)

Comment: I can't use the keyboard backspace signal anymore with this. It just doesn't fire.
main = Signal.map show Keyboard.presses